# summarising console output from inserts into a docker oracle database

Tags: oracle, docker, sqlplus

I am using the official Oracle 23 Docker image. I have a large amount of test data which needs to be run into the database so it's available for developers using the image.

I know I can put the .sql scripts into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/startup` on the image, and they will be run through SQL Plus on the image automatically.

The thing is, I don't want to see:

```
db_1      | 1 row created.
db_1      |
db_1      |
db_1      | 1 row created.
db_1      |
db_1      |
db_1      | 1 row created.
db_1      |
db_1      |
db_1      | 1 row created.
db_1      |
db_1      |
db_1      | 1 row created.
db_1      |
db_1      |
db_1      | 1 row created.
db_1      |
db_1      |
(etc...)
db_1      | Commit complete.
```

In my console output. I'd rather instead just see something like:

```
db_1      | 10,000 rows created.
db_1      |
db_1      |
db_1      | Commit complete.
```

Or even batching into groups of 100 or something would greatly reduce the amount of output.

Is this possible?

I have tried using `INSERT ALL...` but this still prints each insert individually.

The final script should be backwards compatible with 19c if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: Multiple Inserts (your current solution)

If you do:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3);

INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c) VALUES (4, 5, 6);

INSERT INTO table2 (d, e) VALUES (7, 8);
```

Then you get statements for each row:

> ```
> 1 rows affected
> 1 rows affected
> 1 rows affected
> ```

### Option 2: Multiple row inserts using `INSERT ... SELECT`

If you do:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c)
SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 5, 6 FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO table2 (d, e) VALUES (7, 8);
```

Then you get statements for each table:

> ```
> 2 rows affected
> 1 rows affected
> ```

### Option 3: Multiple row inserts using `INSERT ALL`

If you do:

```sql
INSERT ALL
  INTO table1 (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
  INTO table1 (a, b, c) VALUES (4, 5, 6)
  INTO table2 (d, e) VALUES (7, 8)
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Then you get a single statement for all tables:

> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

### Option 4: Wrap inserts in a PL/SQL block

What you can also do is wrap all the `INSERT` statements in a PL/SQL anonymous block:

```sql
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3);
  INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c) VALUES (4, 5, 6);
  INSERT INTO table2 (d, e) VALUES (7, 8);
END;
/
```

Then you get a single statement for success (or failure) of the entire block:

> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

All these statements should be compatible with most (all?) Oracle versions.

[Oracle 11g Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2G7MA1WF)

Comment: I tried option 3 and it still gave me the individual lines in the output

Comment: for each of those, what happens if one insert fails? Do they all need a COMMIT; ?

Comment: @simonalexander2005 If one row fails then the statement fails (option 1 = fails to insert a single row, option 2 = fails to insert all rows for a single table, option 3 & 4 = fails to insert all rows for all tables). Yes, they do need to be committed.

Comment: Thanks. And can the commit be inside the pl/sql block?

Comment: @simonalexander2005 Yes (you can also test it yourself or read Oracle's documentation)